# iOS Security issue: Handle Automatic screenshot of sensitive data when Application going to Background in iOS? Side channel data leakage

Tags: ios, objective-c, security

iOS is automatically taking screen-shots when an application is going to the background state, and show it when its entering foreground. The screenshots can be accessed from outside the App.

It can be a security issue if we have sensitive data in the screen.

This is how I have handled this issue, please suggest if there is any better way.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Add overlay image to prevent automatic screenshot while entering background

    // prepare image to display
self.splashImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    CGFloat angle = [self angleForOrientation:orientation];
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);    
    self.splashImageView.transform = transform;
    self.splashImageView.frame = self.window.frame;
    [self.window addSubview:self.splashImageView];
}



- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if ([_splashImageView superview])
    {
        [_splashImageView removeFromSuperview];
        self.splashImageView = nil;
    }
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}
```

Comment: Based on this, it's not a security issue since you can disable it.

Comment: @MaxWoolf how to disable this?